# How to create a trigger that automatically update a datetime column when a field of the table is updated

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2017

i am trying to create a column that measures the UPDATE_DATE of a row.
I am building a trigger but i have an ambiguity problem regarding the key.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ModDate_location_update
    ON dim_Location
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.dim_Location 
    SET UPDATE_DATE = GETDATE()
    --WHERE INSERT_DATE IN (SELECT INSERT_DATE FROM INSERTED)
    FROM dim_Location X
    JOIN dim_Location Y ON X.NEW_LOCATION_KEY = Y.NEW_LOCATION_KEY
end
```

> Msg 8154, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ModDate_location_update, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 119]
>   The table 'dbo.dim_Location' is ambiguous.

Comment: There is a potentially bigger problem here, which is that your trigger appears to be recursive, because an update on `dim_Location` fires a trigger which again updates that same table.  Is this the intended logic?

Comment: Use the alias in your `UPDATE` clause, however, why are you not referencing `inserted` here? This will update the **entire** table every time you update even a single row; surely that isn't wanted. Seems like you want an `INSTEAD OF` trigger here, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply update all the rows having a PK that appears in the INSERTED virtual table.  EG:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ModDate_location_update
    ON dim_Location
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.dim_Location 
    SET UPDATE_DATE = GETDATE()
    WHERE LOCATION_ID IN (SELECT LOCATION_ID FROM INSERTED)
end
```